# django dj-database-url runs extrem slow

Tags: python, django, django-database

When i setup dj_database_url in my django project on local machine, the migrations and development server run extrem slow. They run already, but extrem slow. when i setup the database in this way everything works normal.

runs normal:

```
# settings.py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'my_db',
        'USER': os.environ.get("USER"),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get("PASSWORD"),
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

runs slow:

```
# settings.py
import dj_database_url

DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default=os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL"))}
```

my .env file

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://user:passwd@localhost:5432/my_db
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in my case the soloution was a simple change. I just change the DATABASE_URL from

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://user:passwd@localhost:5432/my_db
```

to

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://user:passwd@127.0.0.1:5432/my_db
```

and it works!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue is that the `dj_database_url` version is using the wrong database by accident. To double check, I'd change the code to:

```
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(os.environ["DATABASE_URL"])}
```

So that you'll get an error immediately if a `DATABASE_URL` isn't defined.

If you're still having the issue, add:

```
 print "*" * 80
 print dj_database_url.config(os.environ["DATABASE_URL"])
 print "*" * 80
```

to your `settings.py` file so you can see exactly what `dj_database_url` is returning, and compare that to your "hand-written" database config.

Comment: It is returning `********************************************************************************
{}
********************************************************************************`

Comment: Okay, so there's your problem — the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable isn't being set correctly. Are you sure autoenv is setup and running correctly?

Comment: when i type `dj_database_url.config()` in python shell it returns the right values

Comment: i use [django-dotenv](https://github.com/jpadilla/django-dotenv) for accesing the .env file

Comment: In that case, try: `print repr(os.environ["DATABASE_URL"])` to double check that the value there is as you expect. Otherwise, maybe just go with `dj_database_url.config()` and pretend the world isn't a terrible and confusing place?

Comment: `print repr(os.environ["DATABASE_URL"])` prints the correct value. do you recommend autoenv  instead of django-dotenv !?

Comment: Dunno! I don't use either regularly so I can't say.